# Formatting a Word document using interop c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ms-word, office-interop

I am currently trying to add an image, text and then another image. However when I insert the text the first image gets replaced.

```
var footer = document.Content.InlineShapes.AddPicture(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Images\\footer.png").ConvertToShape();
footer.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapTopBottom;
document.Content.Text = input;
var header = document.Content.InlineShapes.AddPicture(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Images\\header.png").ConvertToShape();
header.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapTopBottom;
```

How do I keep both images in my document?

**Update** 
With Rene's answer this is how the document is being presented.
[image]

Comment: @Deduplicator is that why my question got marked down?

Comment: You might find this helpful (it's in VBA but is basically the same as the c# version): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835176.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `Content` is a `Range` object that covers the complete document. A  `Range` object holds all the stuff that is added.

Setting the `Text` property replaces all content of the `Range` including non text-objects.

To insert text and images in a cooperative way use the [`InsertAfter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192427.aspx) method, like so:

```
var footer = document
    .Content
    .InlineShapes
    .AddPicture(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Images\\footer.png")
     .ConvertToShape();
footer.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapTopBottom;

// be cooperative with what is already in the Range present
document.Content.InsertAfter(input);

var header = document
    .Content
    .InlineShapes
    .AddPicture(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Images\\header.png")
    .ConvertToShape();
header.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapTopBottom;
```

If you want to have more control over where you content appears, you can introduce paragraphs, where each paragraph has its own `Range`. In that case your code could look like this:

```
var footerPar = document.Paragraphs.Add();
var footerRange = footerPar.Range;
var inlineshape = footerRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "footer.png");
var footer = inlineshape.ConvertToShape();
footer.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
footer.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapTopBottom;

var inputPar = document.Paragraphs.Add();
inputPar.Range.Text = input;
inputPar.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

var headerPar = document.Paragraphs.Add();
var headerRange = headerPar.Range;
var headerShape = headerRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "header.png");
var header = headerShape.ConvertToShape();
header.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
header.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapTopBottom;
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however its still got the same problem. See updated, i been trying with the ranges, can the insertAfter method be used with an image?

Comment: @sambishop added an option that uses paragraphs but you could as well checkout Sections.

Comment: Worked thank you for all your help, was driving me up the wall. Do you know how to set the new line variable, as the spacing is massive.

Comment: sure, there are how-to's about [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b7k14a4.aspx). Good luck.